# after update to "^0.9.1" error: package org.unimodules.adapters.react.apploader does not exist

Tags: reactjs, react-native

after update to "^0.9.1" get this error on build app stage

Console:
C:\Users\IvanovichDev\Documents\check-dev-geo\mobile\node_modules@unimodules\react-native-adapter\android\src\main\java\org\unimodules\adapters\react\ReactAdapterPackage.java:10: error: package org.unimodules.adapters.react.apploader does not exist
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader;
^
C:\Users\IvanovichDev\Documents\check-dev-geo\mobile\node_modules@unimodules\react-native-adapter\android\src\main\java\org\unimodules\adapters\react\ReactAdapterPackage.java:20: error: package org.unimodules.apploader does not exist
import org.unimodules.apploader.AppLoaderProvider;
^
C:\Users\IvanovichDev\Documents\check-dev-geo\mobile\node_modules@unimodules\react-native-adapter\android\src\main\java\org\unimodules\adapters\react\ReactAdapterPackage.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
AppLoaderProvider.registerLoader(context, "react-native-headless", RNHeadlessAppLoader.class);
^
symbol: class RNHeadlessAppLoader
location: class ReactAdapterPackage
C:\Users\IvanovichDev\Documents\check-dev-geo\mobile\node_modules@unimodules\react-native-adapter\android\src\main\java\org\unimodules\adapters\react\ReactAdapterPackage.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
AppLoaderProvider.registerLoader(context, "react-native-headless", RNHeadlessAppLoader.class);
^
symbol: variable AppLoaderProvider
location: class ReactAdapterPackage
4 errors

Comment: Hello Kolya, did you fixed this error allready? I run into the same issue now. IOS works like a charm, but android isn't finishing building.

Comment: try updating "react-native-unimodules":